# MS Entourage 2008 and quoted-printable encoding

Tags: email, entourage, quoted-printable

I need to send an HTML email. All email clients (Outlook, Thunderbird ..) but Entourage can receive and read this email without major problems. Entourage, though is breaking the content and displays just few lines from the beginning.

My guess is that it has something to do with the way how Entourage handles quoted-printable encoding. The important headers of email as they are set:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

The same behaviour in Entourage occurs when email is sent as multipart/alternative with alternative plain text.
The content of the email is displayd until the character `=00` occurs (encoded NUL?).

Is this Entourage bug behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed those `*=00*` characters. Before sending the email, you need to prepare it for quoted-printable encoding and remove all null characters.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\x00+/', '', $str);
```